# Applying filters to advanced compare view with GitHub

Tags: github

I'm using the GitHub compare view on branches. Here's an example, the repo I'm looking at is private: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/compare/master...commandline.

Is there any way to add the options from --diff-filter to a compare, or a regexp on the files?

(Changes to CSS and new PNG files are just clutter in terms of understanding a branch.)

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way via the GitHub web interface.

You may try out their clients for Windows, Mac or Eclipse if that allows you to, but from the web, it's not possible to currently filter.